# unloading shared library with boost dependency -> crash in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<...> >::dispose()

Tags: c++, boost

I'm observing a strange behavior of a program on macOS (using Qt, boost, and other libs).

The program consists of a main executable and various plugins that are dynamically loaded.

Both the main program and the plugins are *deployed* with `macdeployqt` and `macdeployqtfix` to adjust all the library paths so that are relative to `@loader_path/../Frameworks/...`, e.g.:

```
% otool -L Desktop/myProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/libPluginA.dylib 
Desktop/myProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/libPluginA.dylib:
    @rpath/libPluginA.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libboost_regex-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libboost_system-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 904.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
```

On the development machine all is fine, no crash occurs when quitting.

On a testing machine (virtual machine, pristine macOS 10.15 install, with no programs installed except for XCode Command Line tools for `otool` and `lldb`), the program seems to run fine, but on quit, when unloading the plugins, I get this crash:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x13d186a48)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000124f87766 libPluginA.dylib`boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >::dispose() + 38
    frame #1: 0x0000000124f878fd libPluginA.dylib`boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::re_detail_107500::basic_regex_implementation<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >::dispose() + 77
    frame #2: 0x0000000124f848ae libPluginA.dylib`boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::~basic_regex() + 30
    frame #3: 0x00007fff70edc13c libsystem_c.dylib`__cxa_finalize_ranges + 319
    frame #4: 0x000000010002cd8f dyld`dyld::garbageCollectImages() + 851
    frame #5: 0x00000001000370d6 dyld`dlclose + 191
    frame #6: 0x00007fff70e2fcf8 libdyld.dylib`dlclose + 170
...
    frame #21: 0x000000010000497d myProgram`main + 109
    frame #22: 0x00007fff70e32cc9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

`libPluginA.dylib` is just one of the many plugins that are dynamically loaded.
If functions of a given plugin are not used, then no crash (in that plugin) occurs.

I know this is not minimal or reproducible, but any hint to find out what could be causing this behavior it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a function with a `static` variable of type `boost::regex`:

```
void f(const std::string &h)
{
    boost::cmatch m;
    static boost::regex re("...");
    if(boost::regex_match(h.c_str(), m, re)) { ... }
}
```

removing the `static` keyword fixed the problem.

(still willing to accept an answer from someone that would explain this in detail)